# Smart and automatic button placement

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using LibGDX buttons for touch input(previously used desktop mode and keyboard keys. So far, the button listeners work as intended, but I can't position those buttons the way I want. I tried to look through the documentation and some examples and can't figure out the problem here, but from what I've read few key things I've noticed:

- buttons should be placed in a table
- tables can (and should) be nested
- only the main table should fill the parent.

What I want to accomplish is to have labels (tableLabs) packed at the top (as per the original Mario) and the buttons to be aligned to bottom corners (so button left would be in the bottom left corner and button right at the bottom right) with jump buttons being directly above the direction buttons without regard for the screen size, something similar to having a Java Swing border layout.

Finally, I use simple "->" , "<-" and "^" as placeholders for future button graphics.

So far The result looks like this:
[image: mario labels and buttons]

```
public class Hud implements Disposable{

    public Stage stage;
    public Viewport viewport;

    private Integer worldTimer;
    private float timeCount;
    private static Integer score;

    Label countDownLabel;
    static Label scoreLabel;
    Label timeLabel;
    Label levelLabel;
    Label worldLabel;
    Label marioLabel;

    TextButton butL, butR, butJ;

    public Hud(SpriteBatch spriteBatch){
        worldTimer = 300;
        timeCount = 0;
        score = 0;

        viewport = new FitViewport(SuperMario.WORLDWIDTH, SuperMario.WORLDHEIGHT, new OrthographicCamera());
        stage = new Stage(viewport, spriteBatch);

        Table mainTable = new Table();
//        mainTable.top().center();
        mainTable.setFillParent(true);


        Table tableLabs = new Table();
        tableLabs.top();//align to top
//        table.setFillParent(true);//fill

        countDownLabel  = new Label(String.format("%03d", worldTimer), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        scoreLabel = new Label(String.format("%06d", score), new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        timeLabel =  new Label("TIME", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        levelLabel = new Label("1-1", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        worldLabel = new Label("WORLD", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
        marioLabel = new Label("MARIO", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));

        tableLabs.add(marioLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        tableLabs.add(worldLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        tableLabs.add(timeLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        tableLabs.row();
        tableLabs.add(scoreLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        tableLabs.add(levelLabel).expandX().padTop(10);
        tableLabs.add(countDownLabel).expandX().padTop(10);

//        stage.addActor(table);

        //button setup

        Table butTable = new Table();
        butTable.bottom();
//        table.setFillParent(true);

        TextButton.TextButtonStyle tbs = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
        tbs.font = new BitmapFont();
        butR = new TextButton("b1", tbs);
        butR.setText("->");
        butR.setColor(Color.FIREBRICK);
        butR.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.log("B-right", "pressed");
            }
        });

        butL = new TextButton("b2", tbs);
        butL.setText("<-");
        butL.setColor(Color.FIREBRICK);
        butL.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.log("B-left", "pressed");
            }
        });

        butJ = new TextButton("b3", tbs);
        butJ.setText("^");
        butJ.setColor(Color.FIREBRICK);
        butJ.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.log("B-jump", "pressed");
            }
        });


        butTable.setDebug(true);
        butTable.add(butJ).expandX().padBottom(10).left().expand().padRight(10);
        butTable.add(butJ).expandX().padBottom(10).right().expand().padLeft(10);
        butTable.row();
        butTable.add(butL).expandX().padBottom(10).left().expand().padRight(10);
        butTable.add(butR).expandX().padBottom(10).right().expand().padLeft(10);


        mainTable.add(tableLabs).expand();
        mainTable.row();
        mainTable.add(butTable).expand();
        mainTable.setDebug(true);
//        stage.addActor(butTable);
        stage.addActor(mainTable);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    public void update(float dt){
        timeCount+= dt;
        if(timeCount >=1){
            worldTimer--;
            countDownLabel.setText(String.format("%03d", worldTimer));
            timeCount--;
        }
    }

    public static void addScore(int value){
        score += value;
        scoreLabel.setText(String.format("%06d", score));
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing when setting up your table cells is the *fill* parameter. Calling `expand` on a cell like you're doing makes the cell stretch to fit, but the widget inside the cell will not get bigger unless you also call `fill` on the cell.

So that part near the bottom where you add the two inner tables to the main table should look like this:

```
mainTable.add(tableLabs).expand().fill(); //stretch the inner table to the size of the cell
mainTable.row();
mainTable.add(butTable).expand().fill(); //as above
mainTable.setDebug(true);
stage.addActor(mainTable);
```